# How do I remove empty columns from an Angular Material data table?

Tags: angular, datatable, datatables, angular-material

I have made a data-table in which some columns have blank data, I would like to create a toggle which hides the empty columns.

I am looking for a concept or a way around as I am new to Angular.

After clicking the toggle switch the columns should hide.

[image: I want to hide Product manager, content manager, etc.]

```js
.subscribe(campaignListResponse => {
        this.tableFullData = Object.values(campaignListResponse);
        this.copyTableFullData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(campaignListResponse));
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.tableFullData);

        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filters) => {
          const matchFilter = [];
          const filterArray = filters.split(',');
          const columns = [data.campaign_id, data.campaign.bu, data.campaign.executing_team, data.campaign.campaign_quarter,
            data.campaign.diamond, data.campaign.campaign_imt, data.campaign.campaign_code, data.campaign.campaign_manager,
            data.campaign.campaign_lead_offer, data.campaign.campaign_year, data.campaign.countries_covered,
            data.created_by];
            filterArray.forEach(filter => {
            const customFilter = [];
            columns.forEach(column => customFilter.push(column.toLowerCase().includes(filter)));
            matchFilter.push(customFilter.some(Boolean)); // OR
          });
          return matchFilter.every(Boolean); // AND
        }

        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Please add some code you have written so far, without it we can't help you.

Comment: added a block... if you can let me know what part of the code you want to see.. I can add more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement a function that filters your displayed columns of the `mat-table`. I imagine you have a line like this in your code:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
```

Then in your component you need to write a function that filters `displayedColumns` based on the actual data that you are showing.

This could look something like this (depending on your data model, etc.):

```
public toggle(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
  if (event.checked) {
    const columns = this.getEmptyColumns();
    this.displayedColumns = this.defaultColumns.filter(col => !columns[col]);
  } else {
    this.displayedColumns = this.defaultColumns;
  }
}

public getEmptyColumns(): {[key: string]: boolean} {
  const columns = {};

  this.defaultColumns.forEach(col => {
    columns[col] = this.dataSource.every(element => {
      return !element[col];
    });
  });

  return columns;
}
```

The `toggle` function is triggered by our `mat-slide-toggle` and filters the columns that are displayed based on the data. The `getEmptyColumns` function checks for each property if all rows are empty and returns an object with the property as a key and the value whether or not the column is empty. Based on that we then filter the columns we want to display.

> Check out
>   [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-w4kx56?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   stackblitz. It's a simple example of how you can hide the empy columns
>   with a toggle and should give you an idea how to go about implementing this for your solution.

Note: It looks like your data is nested, meaning you will have to implement some additional logic when retrieving the empty columns as you cannot directly access the data with the nested properties.